# override duplicate device driver for kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

i'm trying to update kernel with my linux device drivers , but kernel provide the same drivers . according to driver precedence in /etc/depmod.d/dist.conf  built-in drivers take precedence over weak-updates. 
there is way to change the precedence in kernel by crating you own config file in /etc/depmod.d/yourdriver.conf 
override sym53c8xx 2.6.32-* weak-updates/sym53c8xx
http://people.redhat.com/jcm/el6/dup/docs/dup_book.pdf

however i'm trying the same thing but it doesn't include my driver after i run depmod . has anyone done that before here ? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://people.redhat.com/jcm/el6/dup/docs/dup_book.pdf had the correct answer , i didn't read it carefully . 
create a conf file in /etc/depmod/foo.conf and add this to file

override foo * weak-updates/foofolder

Answer (score 2):

There is special folder under `/lib/modules/<version>`, i.e. `/lib/modules/<version>/extra`. If you put modules there they will override whatever you have in kernel for the same device. I checked this on Fedora, but I think it's a standard practice.

Comment: This is correct because "extra" folder has higher priority over built-in kernel driver . the problem i have is what if you update your kernel ( modules will go in "weak-update" folder ) and since "weak-update" has lower priority then "built-in" folder . My modules will never load .